# What is the correct 'to wear' verb for body weights?

Tags: word-choice

In attempting to write about wearing ankle weights for the day, I found myself at a loss for which verb was appropriate.

- 巻く seems like it could be appropriate since they wrap around the ankle - in which case, it would also work for wrist weights. By this logic, I'd consider 着る for weighted vests, since they are worn like a normal vest with added straps.
- 締める seems appropriate since they fasten with velcro and straps (which could also work for weighted vests and wrist weights).
- 履く is a possibility since they're worn on the lower body, which would again make 着る the best option for weighted vests. I haven't the foggiest on which would be appropriate for wrist weights in this instance. する, maybe?

Which word would be appropriate for each type of weight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say:

> アンクルウェイトを【つける、足首に巻く、装着する】
>   リストウェイトを【つける、手首に巻く、装着する】
>   ウェイトベストを【着る、着用する、maybe 装着する、つける】

Comment: I am not sure if the つける is 着ける or 付ける...

Comment: I believe it can be either, as naruto demonstrates above.

Comment: So I'd use つける in Hiragana, like most people do on the Internet...　(ウェイトをつけて>>156000 results, ウェイトを付けて>>99200, ウェイトを着けて>>4950)

Answer (score 1):

- ウェイトを付ける/着ける is the safest, common choice in this case. Both for ankle and wrist weights.
- ウェイトを巻く is fine if you want to use a more specific verb.
- ウェイトを装着する is also OK, but may sound too technical in casual conversations.
- ウェイトを締める is acceptable, but sounds a bit off. It's usually specifically used for belts.
- ウェイトを着る: wrong.
- ウェイトを履く: wrong because it's only for <s>shoes and socks</s> shoes, socks, trousers, underpants, etc.

Comment: 靴と靴下だけではなく、ズボンやパンツも履きますよね。

Comment: @marasai 仰る通りです…修正しました

Comment: Given that you mention 付ける/着ける are appropriate for wrist and ankle weights, would they be incorrect for weighted vests?

Comment: @jimbotherisenclown Sorry, I was not aware that you're also asking for vests. See choko's answer for that.